# Parse polymorphic child with Moshi

Tags: json, moshi

I ask here since I don't think this is a relevant question for Moshi GitHub issues.

I have card **json** variant #1:

```
{ "id":"some id",
  "type":"GENERIC_MESSAGE",
  "data": { "title":"Small error",
            "message":"Please update some info",
            "type":"ERROR"
          }
}
```

and variant #2:

```
{ "id":"some id",
  "type":"DATA_SCIENCE",
  "data": { "cardData": 
             { "message":"You spent...",
               "title":"...last month"}
             }    
          }
}
```

Here is my code for generic JSON adapter:

```
public class CardJsonAdapter
{
  @Keep
  static class CardJson
  {
    String id;
    Card.Type type;
    JSONObject data; <--- HERE is my problem
  }

  @FromJson
  Card fromJson(@NonNull final CardJson json)
    throws IOException
  {
    try
    {
      CardData data = getCardData(json);
      return new Card(json.id, json.type, data);
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
      throw new JsonDataException("Can not parse Card json");
    }
  }

  private CardData getCardData(final @NonNull CardJson json)
    throws JSONException
  {
    CardData data = null;

    switch (json.type) 
    ...
  }
...
}
```

So by the card `type`, I already know how to parse `data` object. But I don't know how to get something generic in data. I can not set the type to `String` since **Moshi** crashes with `BEGIN_OBJECT not expected error`, I can not put `Map<String, Object>` it also fails with the error with the second **json**. And `JsonObject` is not crashing with parsing but is completely empty after parsing.

I can not find anything yet, so I'm asking your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
public class CardJsonAdapter
{
  @Keep
  static class CardDataJson 
  {
    String title;
    String message;
    String type;
    CardDataJson cardData;
  }

  @Keep
  static class CardJson
  {
    String id;
    Card.Type type;
    CardDataJson data;
  }

  @FromJson
  Card fromJson(@NonNull final CardJson json)
    throws IOException
  {
    try
    {
      CardData data = getCardData(json);
      return new Card(json.id, json.type, data);
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
      throw new JsonDataException("Can not parse Card json");
    }
  }

  private CardData getCardData(final @NonNull CardJson json)
    throws JSONException
  {
    CardData data = null;

    switch (json.type) 
    ...
  }
...
}
```

**Moshi** is just nulling fields that are not present in json